# How to apply different CSS styles to 2 elements with the same class name?

Tags: css, html

I created a website that has different navigation menus. In 2 menus, I use the same HTML class element.

I have a .css file that styles that class element in 1 menu. However, in another menu, I would like to style the elements differently.

Yes, I know I can rename the class name, but to be consistent with what I have right now in the structure of my markup, and also the fact that the class name is used to style multiple other elements, how would I be able to apply different styles to 2 different elements with the same class name?

Can this be done using some kind of if statement condition in CSS?

For example, in 1.html:

```
<div class="classname"> Some code </div>
```

In 2.html:

```
<div class="classname"> Some different code </div>
```

Since I just want to style this "one" element differently in 2.html, can I just add an id attribute along with the class attribute, and use both the id and class and somehow as the selector?

Once again, I would not like to remove the class name at all, if possible.

Thanks!

Comment: Are these menus wrapped in some other HTML structure that might have a class on it?

Comment: @lucuma, yes, that's why its difficult

Comment: Are the parent classes different or is it identical html?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'll just add that typically when there are multiple menus you might have them wrapped in a different structure. Take for instance:

```
<nav class='mainnav'><div class="classname one"> Some code </div></nav>

<div class='wrapper'><div class="classname"> Some different code </div></div>
```

You can easily target these:

```
.mainnav>.classone {}
.wrapper>.classone {}
```

Or if the parent html has a class:

```
<div class='ancestor1'><div><div class="classname one"> Some code </div></div></div>
<div class='ancestor2'><div><div class="classname one"> Some code </div></div></div>

.ancestor1 .classname {}
.ancestor2 .classname {}
```

Obviously this depends on where in the html they might be.

Comment: The element in 2.html has multiple nested classes, of which those classes are the parents, grandparents, etc. of that class. The other element in 1.html has only 1 parent class.

Comment: As long as one of those parent classes is different between the two the second code set will work.  I've renamed it ancestor1 and ancestor2 to hopefully make it a little clearer.

Answer (score 8):

You can add another class name to each element.

```
<div class="classname one"> Some code </div>
<div class="classname two"> Some different code </div>
```

And then aplpy different rules to them:

```
.classname.one {
    border: 1px solid #00f;    
}

.classname.two {
    border: 1px solid #f00;    
}
```

**Edit:**

Updated Demo link: http://jsfiddle.net/8C76m/2/

If you must keep only one class for each element, you may try the `nth-child` or `nth-of-type` pseudo-class:

```
.classname:first-child {
    font-size: 2em; 
}

.classname:nth-of-type(2) {
    color: #f00;
}
```

Ref:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstchild.asp and http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-of-type.asp

Comment: right, but I would like not to rename the class name. I like to keep it the way it is. Can I just add another class name attribute for one of the elements?

Comment: We are not renaming the class names. We just add another class to the elements.

Comment: Can I add a 2nd class name to just 1 of the elements with the same class name, or do both elements with the same class name need to have a 2nd class name to work?

Comment: You can add another class to just one of the elements: See http://jsfiddle.net/2499Z/

Answer (score 3):

Just give each one a different id

```
#firsthtml .classname {  

}

#sechtml .classname { 

}
```

Be sure to use the space, as #firsthtml.classname is something totally different.

```
<div class="classname" id="firsthtml"></div>
<div class="classname" id="sechtml"></div>
```

---

You could also use two different class names

```
<div class="classname secondclassname"></div>
```

Define secondclassname in your css with the additional css

```
.classname.secondclassname{

}
```

Comment: what if I don't want to touch the attributes in 1.html, but solely focus on the element in 2.html? Can I just add <div class"classname" id="thing"> Some other code </div> ? Then access it like you said?

Comment: Yes. You can do just that. Just add the the id to 2.html div and add CSS to that one.

Comment: hmm, for some reason when I do that, the "active" menu containing that element freezes, and I cannot access any other navigation menus. Does this have anything to do with the fact that I'm using bootstrap?

Comment: Seeing the source would help me better understand your problem. Yes bootstrap does play a huge factor but it may be something very simple.

To be clear, you are aware you can create a secondary css file and edit with in it correctly? This way you don't mess with the bootstrap css structure?

Comment: if I style classname.secondclassname in 2.html, but in 1.html, I don't have a 2nd class name attribute, will that still work?

Comment: Yes. Just be sure to keep the CSS for 1.html the same while then adding classname.secondclassname

Comment: If you're attaching the ID and class to the same element, the selector *should not* have a space. You're also missing the leading `.` in your double class selectors (where you correctly leave out the space).

Comment: Am I reading your edit correctly, or did you just add in the space in one of the places where I said you correctly left it out?

Comment: I removed it completely as I don't like that solution. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do something like this:

```
<div class="classname"> Some code </div>
<div class="classname second"> Some different code </div>
```

And the CSS for the first `.classname` would be something like that:

```
.classname:not(.second) {}
```

For the second element it goes easily:

```
.classname.second {}
```

Comment: No need for the `:not` in `.classname:not` as `.classname.second` has a higher specificity than `.classname`.

Comment: Yes, just if you need to use ruleset for the first element.

Comment: Then I would just override the properties in the `.classname.second`

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a poor way of doing it, the suggestions from previous answers are helpful, but try this maybe:

First menu:

```
<div class="classname"> Some code </div>
```

Second menu:

```
<div class="classname" style="margin-bottom:0;color:Black;width:100px;height:100px"> Some other code </div>
```