# Select elements inside a specific container (div or form)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I know by doing `element>elements` we can use CSS selector to select all `elements` inside the parent `element`.

Buy if there are a couple of containers `element` of same kind and we only want to select elements in a specific parent `element`, is there a way to do it?

I have tried `#elementID>elements` and `.elementClass>elements` but neither worked.

simplified code:

```
<div id="id" class = "class">
  <form id = "form" class = "c">
    <button class="test">foo</button>
    <button class="test">foo</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

CSS not working: `#id > button{}`,  `.class >button` ,`#form >button{}`,`.c >button{}`

If I do `div > button{}` it works but I have a couple more div containers with `button`elements in it and I want them to have different CSS effects.

**The whole picture is here** :https://jsfiddle.net/j9b7mhLp/1/

**Specifically I am targeting the "sign up" and "cancel" two buttons in the modal.**

Comment: Why can't you use `#form button` ?

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4910077/select-all-child-elements-recursively-in-css

Comment: these code are working `#form>button {}
.c > button {}` refer the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j9b7mhLp/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is too vague. Just place an ID on the element and select it that way.

Descendant selectors use (simply) `form button` (as opposed to `form > button`)

Answer (score 2):

If you're interested in changing the buttons with JavaScript, here's some code to consider:

```
var buts = document.forms["form"].querySelectorAll("button");
buts[0].style.background="green";
buts[1].style.background="blue";
```

live [demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qmraom)

Comment: Oh God.. why would anyone do it this way? :)

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
#id > button:nth-of-type(1) {/*place your css here*/}
#id > button:nth-of-type(2) {/*place your css here*/}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this

```
 .test {  }
 .test:first-child {  }
```

Please refer this link : [**First and nth Child**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24771113/5635098)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have more buttons in the same form, like this:

```
<div id="id" class = "class">
  <form id = "form" class = "c">
    <button class="test">foo</button>
    <button class="test">foo</button>
    <button class="test">foo</button>
    <button class="test">foo</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Can you add a specific class for that divs?

```
<div id="id" class = "class">
  <form id = "form" class = "c">
    <button class="test">foo</button>
    <button class="test">foo</button>
    <button class="test specific">foo</button>
    <button class="test specific">foo</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

The you can use this css code:

```
#id > .test.specific { //whatever }
```

Answer (score 1):

this seems to working for me. Please check if your custom css is overriding this.

```css
#One > form > button {
  color: red;
  background: purple;
}

#Two > form > button {
  color: red;
  background: purple;
}
```

```html
<div id="One" class="class">
  <form id = "form" class = "c">
    <button class="test">foo</button>
    <button class="test">foo</button>
  </form>  
</div>

<div id="Two" class="class1">
  <form id = "form" class = "c">
    <button class="test">foo</button>
    <button class="test">foo</button>
  </form>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#form button {
//your css here
}
```

buttons are inside form , you can select them like this.

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax errors, please fix them. You shouldn't use spaces when defining attributes in HTML. In this case `ids` and `classes`.

```
<div id="id" class="class">
  <form id="form" class="c">
    <button class="test">foo</button>
    <button class="test">foo</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Now, to select buttons in this exact example there are several ways. If only they have a class 'test' then you can simply select them with the class selector:

```
.test {}
```

If not, you can do it this way as well:

```
form#id > button {}
```

Or, to have more proper targeting depending on the class:

```
form#id > .test
```

Even this will work if you want to select only two buttons and not others in the form:

```
form#id > button:first-child, form#id > button:nth-child(2) {}
```

However, your issue was with the syntax HTML errors.

Comment: what do you mean HTML errors? the HTML is fine. it could be neater, but there aren't any syntax errors there.

Comment: He /she has spacing in class and id defining. Not every browser ignores that and I do not know which one is he/she using.

Comment: there aren't any spaces in the class names or ID names. white space is mostly insignificant in html.

Comment: The only place in fact in OP's question where white space matters is in the CSS (`form#id > button {}` vs `form#id>button {}`)

Comment: That is false. There is space in defining the class, check the OP's question again. I'm now testing on IE and it is not rendering, that's why I posted it.

Comment: you mean `class = "class"` as opposed to `class="class"` ?

Comment: The white space in the CSS is significant. in fact, it will stay there unless you use an optimiser that is not up to spec. (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4910077/select-all-child-elements-recursively-in-css). i also have no idea which version of IE is causing problems, but i can tell you it's not anything above IE8. (barring misery with quirks mode)

Comment: White space in CSS IS significant, but that never was the issue here, was it? :)

Comment: concerning OP's question and your remark, it was ;)
i still can't get IE to misbehave when messing with the spacing tho. :\ everything above 8 just fixes it by itself.

Comment: No it doesn't. Even the developers' tools are giving the error in the log. I do not see how it was, since I've posted the CSS with the white spaces.. :)