# why same style applies to both components having different scss files with different styles in React?

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, styling

I have two Components Login and Register with different separate styles.

//       Login.jsx

```
    import "../../Login.scss";
       function Login() {
        return (
           <>
                <div>Login</div>
           </>
            );
                      }

   export default Login;
```

// Register.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import "../../Register.scss";
function Register() {
  return (
    <>
      <div>Register </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default Register;
```

I have set different background color of both files, that is

// Login.scss

```
div{
  background-color: red;
}
```

//  Register.scss

```
div{
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

I have rendered both components in App.js
but both the components have only one style applied i-e Register.scss even I have not imported it in Login.jsx but still  in Login.jsx getting the style of Register.scss instead of Login.scss

1. what could be the possibl reason?
2. Can I apply same className styles by differentiating with different import paths?

[image: Edit magical-wind-748qjb]

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the way that Cascading Style sheets work. The `.div` will adhere to the LAST style rule, as the file is read.

The post below contains the answer.

[How to use the same name classes but in separate styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44941511/how-to-use-the-same-name-classes-but-in-separate-styles)

Comment: If I am not wrong, it means the browser will always make one css file for all the css files.

Comment: Yes that is correct, all the CSS files will become bundled.

Answer (score 1):

If you're working with Sass, you may have noticed that any element using the same class name can overwrite each other. Fortunately, there is a solution to this problem: CSS modules. CSS modules are CSS files that scope class names and animation names locally by default.

To implement CSS modules in your project, follow these steps:

1. Rename your style file by adding "module" before the .scss extension, for example: `Login.module.scss`.
2. Change your import statement to import the module, like so: `import styles from "../../Login.module.scss";`.
3. Add styles to your elements or components using the syntax `<div className={styles.div}>I'm an example</div>`.

By using CSS modules, you can avoid conflicts between class names and ensure that your styles are applied correctly.